# Displaying multiple images from the same element name in xsl

Tags: xml, image, xslt

I'm trying to display multiple images that have the same name in my xml using xslt. Here is an example of the 'restaurant' element and its children in my XML:

```
<cuisine type="Indian">
<restaurant>
    <name>Indu</name>
    <logo>indu_logo.png</logo>
    <pics>Website-Heirloom.jpg</pics>
    <pics>Website-Snapper.jpg</pics>
    <url>http://indudining.com.au</url>
    <address>350 George Street, (entry via Angel Place) Sydney</address>
    <phonenumber>02 9223 0158</phonenumber>
    <openinghours>12:00PM to late</openinghours>
    <delivery>Minimum Price: $50. Delivery Fee: $10</delivery>
    <description>INDU is a celebration of southern Indian and Sri Lankan village culture, flavours and local hospitality.</description>
    <menu>Desserts, Paratha, Basmati rice</menu>
    <onlinebooking>Yes</onlinebooking>
    <event>No</event>
</restaurant>
```

I'm trying to build a styled page to display this information, and I've managed to display everything I need except the "pics", as when I call 'pics' it only (understandably) displays the first picture. Here is the current XSLT that I've got:

```
 <xsl:template match="/">

   <html>
     <head> 

        <title>Restaurant Info</title>      


      </head>
      <body>

        <h1>Restaurant List (A-Z):</h1>

        <xsl:for-each select="cuisine/restaurant">

            <xsl:sort select="name"/>

            <SPAN> <img src="images/{logo}" width="100"/> </SPAN>
            <BR />
            <SPAN STYLE="font-weight:bold">Restauraunt Name: </SPAN>
            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
            <BR />
            <SPAN STYLE="font-weight:bold">Description: </SPAN> 
            <xsl:value-of select="description" /> 
            <BR /> 
            <SPAN STYLE="font-weight:bold">URL: </SPAN> 
            <xsl:value-of select="url" /> 
            <BR /> 
            <SPAN STYLE="font-weight:bold">Address: </SPAN> 
            <xsl:value-of select="address" /> 
            <BR/>
            <SPAN> <img src="images/{pics}" width="200"/> </SPAN>
            <BR />


            <P/>
            <hr/>

        </xsl:for-each>



      </body>
   </html>

</xsl:template>
```

What is the best way to display both pics without directly referring to the files? I need my xslt to be applicable to multiple XML documents with the same node names.

So far I've tried: making another 'for-each' loop within my main for-each loop and calling 'pics' within it, putting brackets after 'pics()' hoping it would step through each one, calling the pics with 'xsl:value-of' instead of  and making a new template called  and putting  in the body. None of this has worked (though maybe I did it wrong) so I didn't save the code I came up with but if someone knows how to do it and doesn't feel like I've given it a good enough go to deserve hearing how, let me know and ill gladly re-write my incorrect code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another `<xsl:for-each>` loop for the `<pics>` as below.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Restaurant Info</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Restaurant List (A-Z):</h1>
            <xsl:for-each select="cuisine/restaurant">
                <xsl:sort select="name" />
                ...
                <xsl:for-each select="pics">
                    <SPAN>
                        <img src="images/{.}" width="200" />
                    </SPAN>
                </xsl:for-each>
                ...
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Output

```
<SPAN>
    <img src="images/Website-Heirloom.jpg" width="200" />
</SPAN>
<SPAN>
    <img src="images/Website-Snapper.jpg" width="200" />
</SPAN>
```

Comment: THANKYOU! I did try the second loop, however I didn't quote the images using "images/{.}". Lesson learnt (: